# VBA Outlook - Get "last modified by" using MAPI

Tags: vba, outlook, mapi

I am using `MAPI` to get details of email into my database. Now it seems that outlook captures **Last Modified time**.  But I am not able to find any helpful articles on how to capture the "last modified by" in outlook.

I need to know how I can achieve this using `VBA Outlook` with `MAPI` or if there is any other way of getting this done.

Answer (score 1):

Extended MAPI can only be used from C++ or Delphi. There is no way you can do that from VBA.

Why do you need to use MAPI? Have you looked into using the Outlook Object Model and the MailItem.LastModificationTime property in particular?